# How to use SqlDependencyEx with .Net Core in Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr, sqldependencyex

I spent a good amount of today trying to get SqlDependencyEx working with signalR Core in my website today. I wanted to monitor a database table for changes and then update a number on the site via signalR with counts of specific queries.

However, while it all works I am not sure I am using SqlDependencyEx correctly inside of my controller. This is the first time doing a MVC project in C# and I've found limited examples of how to implement it. Even the [GitHub](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener) page for SqlDependencyEx isn't helpful because the website project uses a mock up of the table repository. This is what I have set up:

In ConfigureServices

```
services.AddSingleton<SqlDependencyEx>(sp => {
            var sd = new SqlDependencyEx("Server=myserver; Database=mydatabase; Trusted_Connection=True;",
                "mydatabase",
                "mytable");
            sd.Start();  
            return sd;
        });
```

In my controller (which is just the home controller because I an using React views)

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private readonly SqlDependencyEx _tracking;

    public HomeController(SqlDependencyEx tracking, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        _tracking = tracking;
        _tracking.TableChanged += (o, args) => { OnChange(serviceProvider);};                
    }

    private void OnChange(IServiceProvider sp) {
        if(MyHub.ConnectedIds.Count > 0) {
            //get contexts via service providors
            var context = sp.GetService(typeof(DbContext)) as DbContext;
            var hubcontext = sp.GetService(typeof(IHubContext<MyHub>)) as IHubContext<MyHub>;

            //query count and update via singalR
            int countA = context.mytable.Where(x => x.value == 1).Count();
            hubcontext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("countA", countA);

            int countB = context.mytable
                .Include(t => t.othertable)                    
                .Where(t => t.othertable.value >= 1)
                .Count();
            hubcontext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("countB", countB);
        }
    }

    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I decided to go with a static class that takes a service provider object and set it up in the `StartUp.Configure`method.

In StartUp.cs I change the Configure method to a different overload that provides me the service provider:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime lifetime, IServiceProvider sp)
{
    var props = new dashboard.Models.Tracking.Tracker.Props {
            dbConn = (sp.GetService<DATABASEContext>() as COTSContext).Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString,
            dbName = "DATABASE",
            dbTable = "TABLE"
        };

    Models.Tracking.Tracker.Start(props, sp);
}
```

Made a static class `Tracker` that has the method `Start(Tracker.Props props, IServiceProvider sp)`

Tracker Class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ServiceBrokerListener.Domain;
using PROJECT.Models.Queries;

namespace PROJECT.Models.Tracking
{
    public static class Tracker
    {
        public struct Props { public string dbConn, dbName, dbTable; }
        private static SqlDependencyEx dependency;
        public static void Start(Tracker.Props props, IServiceProvider sp)
        {
            if (dependency == null)
            {
                dependency = new SqlDependencyEx(props.dbConn, props.dbName, props.dbTable, identity: 1);
                RegisterEvents(dependency, sp);
                dependency.Start();
            }
        }

        private static void RegisterEvents(SqlDependencyEx dp, IServiceProvider sp)
        {
            dp.TableChanged += (obj, e) =>
            {
                if (MyHub.ConnectedIds.Count > 0)
                {
                    //db and hub context from service provider
                    var context = sp.GetService(typeof(DATABASEContext)) as DATABASEContext;
                    var hubcontext = sp.GetService(typeof(IHubContext<MyHub>)) as IHubContext<MyHub>;

                    //call hub to launch event, db context has extension for count query
                    hubcontext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("countA", context.GetCountA())
                    hubcontext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync("countB", context.GetCountB())
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```